# How to tell scikit-learn for which label the F-1/precision/recall score is given (in binary classification)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, binary-data

As explained in [this article](http://nlpers.blogspot.com/2007/10/f-measure-versus-accuracy.html), it matters for calculating the F-1 score (that is, for calculating recall and precision) whether those calculations are based on the positive or negative class. For example, if I have a skewed dataset with 1% labels of category A and 99% labels of category B and I am just assigning A the positive category and classify all test items as positive, my F-1 score will be very good. How do I tell scikit-learn which category is the positive category in a binary classification? (If helpful, I can provide code.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933561/how-to-specify-positive-label-when-use-precision-as-scoring-in-gridsearchcv

Comment: "For example, if I have a skewed dataset with 1% labels of category A and 99% labels of category B and I am just assigning A the positive category and classify all test items as positive, my F-1 score will be very good." How would your F1-score be good? Wouldn't your precision be 0.01 and your recall 1, meaning an F1-score of about 0.0198?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For binary classification, `sklearn.metrics.f1_score` will by default make the assumption that 1 is the positive class, and 0 is the negative class. If you use those conventions (`0` for category B, and `1` for category A), it should give you the desired behavior. It is possible to override this behavior by passing the `pos_label` keyword argument to the `f1_score` function.

See: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Comment: Thanks also from for this answer. However, is there any reference from the official documentation therefore?

Comment: Reading the manual page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html, `pos_label` defaults to 1 as the positive class, but it can be overridden.