# How to specify positive label when use precision as scoring in GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, scoring

```
model = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(
        estimator = est, 
        param_grid = param_grid,
        scoring = 'precision',
        verbose = 1,
        n_jobs = 1,
        iid = True,
        cv = 3)
```

In `sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y, y_pred,pos_label=[0])`, I can specify the positive label, how can I specify this in GridSearchCV too?

If there is no way to specify, when using custom scoring, how can I define?

I have tried this:

```
custom_score = make_scorer(precision_score(y, y_pred,pos_label=[0]),  
                          greater_is_better=True)
```

but I got error:

```
NameError: name 'y_pred' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), you can pass any `kwargs` into `make_scorer` and they will be automatically passed into the `score_func` callable.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, make_scorer
custom_scorer = make_scorer(precision_score, greater_is_better=True,  pos_label=0)
```

Then you pass this `custom_scorer` to `GridSearchCV`:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(est, ..., scoring=custom_scorer)
```